# What is the SIMPLEST way to setup two-way hostname resolution between Windows 7 Host and Ubuntu Linux VMWare Guest?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hostname, wins-server

Starting from a clean Windows 7, I installed VMWare Player and then inside it I installed Ubuntu.

Both OS's can ping each other by IP address, but hostnames won't resolve. What's the easiest way to fix that, other than hard-coding static IPs in their respective hosts files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install samba` - `\\linuxhost\share` works from windows, and `smbmount` works from linux.

Answer (score 0):

enable wins resolution on ubuntu or enable dns server on windows

Comment: for a less dynamic approach you can modify host files on both